# Missing icons after memory move

Tags: app-icons

I formated my SD card as internal use, then moved various programs from internal to the SD card. All went well except the icons for the moved programs are gone from the phone screens. How do I get them back?

Answer (score 0):

You should reboot your device to resolve this matter. After the the icon cache rebuilds (after reboot), then recreate shortcuts and widgets on your home screen.